# On the decibels of a Heartbeat

Tags: acoustics, distance

I am trying to gauge the strength of the super-senses of a character from a novel, and I am seeing exactly the decibel range he can hear. The situation is being able to hear heartbeats, but I am finding difficulty finding a range for the intensity of a heartrate at its centrepoint, in order to calculate out its intensity at different distances.

What exactly is this "central intensity" of an average heartbeat.

Note: Just for clarification, by "Central Intensity", I just mean the intensity of sound before diluted by distance via Inverse Square Law.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum and minimum [pressures exerted by a typical human heart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_pressure) are around 120/80 [torr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millimetre_of_mercury). You could in principle take this 40 torr amplitude and put it into the definition of a [sound pressure level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure), comparing it to the standard level of human hearing of 20 µPa.

However, you have the complicated problem of an [impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching#Non-electrical_examples) which prevents nearly all of the sound of a heartbeat from escaping into the air. This is why you can hear someone’s heartbeat if you put your ear to their chest, or if you connect your ear to their chest with a stethoscope, but you cannot generally hear someone’s heartbeat if you are not touching them.  The effectiveness of an impedance match will be different for a fat person versus a skinny person, or for a clothed person versus a naked person, so you are unlikely to find a standard value.

Comment: So I can assume 20 µPa for a baseline. I do not require 100% accuracy, just something close enough to be a plausible assumption when I put it into an inverse square formula?

Comment: I found an online calculator that takes more into account, what should I put for the initial measured distance, should it just be the edge of the heart?